# Typescript error when constructor argument is child of class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Typescript is generating errors when I do the following. I am not sure how to avoid them.

```
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}

class Base {
  constructor(arg: Parent) {
  } 
}

class Extension extends Base {
  constructor(arg: Child) {
    super(arg);
  }
}
```

Comment: *What* errors? Give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Error is the argument "is not assignable to type " type of error. So child class is not assignable to type parent class.

Comment: @user1732055 I cannot reproduce this. [Your code compiles fine.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(arg%3A%20Parent)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Extension%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(arg%3A%20Child)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super(arg)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D). Provide enough code that we can actually see the error you see.

Comment: THe error was due to a method returning a value while the parent class wasn't returning one. So it was breaking the chain. Thanks for looking into  it!